# Double Pressing j Key In Terminal - Strange Behavior

Tags: shell, terminal, keyboard

I'm facing a strange behavior when ever I double press "j" key in terminal only.

Every time that happens, the key mode changes to behave to the following:

"j" becomes up
"k" become down

And the terminal starts cycling through command history.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
Desktop:        KDE

Comment: What shell are you using? `j` and `k` are usually down and up respectively in the shell's Vi command line editing mode (reflecting the keys' use in the Vi editor). Usually though, you would press `Esc` first to get into "normal" mode for these keys to have that effect, and usually the shell is in Emacs (not Vi) command line editing mode, unless you change this yourself through `set -o vi` or, in some shells, by setting `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` to `vi` or `vim`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
It directed me to find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

It was from [bash-it key bindings](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/dff892e0a31e3e2797d5406099cb8513b59e5eb4/themes/ramses/ramses.theme.bash#L96).

```
bind '"jj":vi-movement-mode'
```

I commented out the line with `#` and restarted my terminal.

Now everything is ok.

Comment: You may want to check whether there's a similar `kk` key binding, possibly?